# What's the fastest way to track an address

Tags: block

I'm using the websocket subscribe block, There is a delay of about 2-3 seconds.Is there a faster way?

Answer (score 4):

Running a geyser plugin. Or better would be setting up a Webhook and listening to the address with a provider who does this for you like Helius or HelloMoon.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "onAccountChange" method in solanaWeb3.js package.